# WWW::Mechanize get content from page

Tags: perl, ubuntu, vbulletin

I've used [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize) to login to the site.

Now that we are logged in, I want to make `WWW::Mechanize` script go to `payments.php` and then find the active user subscription (for example VIP Access) (class: `<p class="description">`).

From this I want to then read what that is, then select the correct action. For example if users package states `VIP Small` then print `PKG: VIP Small` and if users package states `VIP Full` then print `PKG: VIP Full`.

Does anyone know of a way to do this? Code used so far (being coded in my Ubuntu virtual machine):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use WWW::Mechanize;

my $forum = "http://localhost/forums/forum.php";

print "Username\r\n";
my $username = <>;
chomp($username);

print "Password\r\n";
my $password = <>;

# do login
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(agentcheck => 1, agent => 'Perl WWW::Mechanize');
$mech->get($forum);
$mech->submit_form(form_number => 1, fields => { vb_login_username => $username, vb_login_password = $password });

print "this far";
$mech->follow_link(text => "Click here if your browser does not automatically redirect you.");
```

Comment: Better copy/paste code instead of showing snapshot...

Comment: I don't understand what "so from this I want to then read what that is, then select the correct action" means.  We need more details.  What exactly does "go to payments.php" mean?  Where is payments.php?  Everything that Mech does is just simulating browser actions, so describe it in terms of clicks or submits.

Comment: Andy: I need the script to browse to the page of payments.php which is in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need

```
$mech->get('http://localhost/forums/payments.php');
```

but I cannot help you get information from there without seeing the HTML of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse result HTML file. I recommend to use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath for such tasks:

```
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content( $mech->content() );

my ($description) = $tree->findvalues('//p[ @class = "description" ]');
```